# Ajax.BeginForm driving me crazy

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.net

### ASP.NET MVC3

I have a partial view that is initially rendered inside a div. The following is the partial code:

```
@model Venue.Models.Validation.CustomerRequestModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js"></script>

@{ Html.RenderPartial("Message"); }
@Html.ValidationSummary()

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
            "Customer",
            "Service",
            null,
            new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "post",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                LoadingElementDuration = 100,
                LoadingElementId = "loading-customer",
                OnBegin = "hideSubmitButton",
                OnSuccess = "hideForm",
                OnComplete = "showSubmitButton",
                OnFailure = "showErrorMessage",
                UpdateTargetId = "formclientes",
            },
            new
            {
                id = "customer-form"
            }))
{
    // Fields are all type="text" although some are numbers.
    <input type="text" name="Address" class="clientes_form" />
}
```

The action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Customer(CustomerRequestModel customer)
{
  // ...
}
```

In the immediate window, this is what I get:

```
this.Request.IsAjaxRequest()
false
```

Why?!

Comment: Hi Fabio... I using your code, but in the Action I tried to change the customer property, like : customer.Name = "NewName" and return the View(customer), but the UI didnt updated ... Do you know why?

Comment: In this case, I used Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm, because I wanted to return a partial view (so that only a portion of the page would be updated). If your objective is the same, you should return like this: return this.PartialView("PartialViewName", customer);. If this doesn't answer your question, post a new one and provide me with a link to access it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should include jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js if you have

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

in your web.config file, which is default enabled by MVC3 RC2.
And also delete the last 3 (MicrosoftAjax, MicrosoftMvcAjax and MicrosoftMvcValidation)script references, because you don't need them when using unobtrusive version.

More info about unobtrusive Ajax by [Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html)